# Menu Fechando sozinho

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Estou com um menu em javascript e meu conhecimento em javascript é quase nulo. E infelizmente esse menu no mobile ele está fechando sozinho ... e como não tenho muito conhecimento estou sofrendo para solucionar esse problema.

Aqui está o site em mobile e vou deixar o codigo abaixo.

Menu fechando sozinho : http://mobt.me/ddc6

Codigo :

```
        // Header Menu Mobile Nav
    if (jQuery('.menu')) {
        jQuery('.nav-toggler').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).next('.menu').addClass('open');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        jQuery('.menu').on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        jQuery('body').on('click', function (e) {
            jQuery('.menu').removeClass('open');
        });

        jQuery('#closeMenu').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery('.menu').removeClass('open');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Após o site ser totalmente carregado o menu não fechou sozinho Axcse

Comment: tem algum script que detecta se o mouse esta sobre/deixando de ficar sobre o menu?

Comment: Aqui Continua fechando independente do tempo que deixa carregando o site... 

E não, até onde sei só tem isso sobre o menu para mobile

Comment: entao... aqui ele fecha mesmo com o cursor sobre os links... bizarro. mas ele fecha so quando faz toggle na classe ".open"

Comment: bom, eu acho que é isso, o seu script, começa verificando o clique no ".nav-toggler", dai se foi clicado, ele adiciona a classe ".open" no elemento com classe ```.menu``` ai prossegue o script, entenda isso como um computador processando o script. o proximo bloco detecta de novo clique no ".menu", depois detecta um clique no elemento "body" que é o corpo da pagina, se foi clicado ele remove a classe ".open" do ".menu", e acho que seu problema é esse. porque o ".nav-toggler" está dentro da tag body, dai o script ao mesmo tempo que adiciona a classe ele remove em seguida

Comment: Sera que se eu tirar a função de clicar no body ele fecha o menu resolve ?
Por que ai fica funcionando apenas a função que precisa clicar no X para fechar

Comment: Bom abri mão da função de clicar no body e fechar o menu e ele parou de fechar sozinho... 

obrigado por me ajudar a ver o script =)

Comment: vou colocar como resposta aqui e vc da o check

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha resposta. Não é preciso remover nada. Tirar a funcionalidade do click no body não é a melhor saída.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bom, eu acho que é isso, o seu script, começa verificando o clique no "`.nav-toggler`", dai se foi clicado, ele adiciona a classe "`.open`" no elemento com classe `.menu` ai prossegue o script, entenda isso como um computador processando o script. o proximo bloco detecta de novo clique no "`.menu`", depois detecta um clique no elemento "`body`" que é o corpo da pagina, se foi clicado ele remove a classe "`.open`" do "`.menu`", e acho que seu problema é esse. porque o "`.nav-toggler`" está dentro da tag `body`, dai o script ao mesmo tempo que adiciona a classe ele remove em seguida. se resolve apenas removendo o bloco:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', function (e) {
  jQuery('.menu').removeClass('open');
});
```

ao invés disso, utilize outra tecnica para detectar o clique fora do menu:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385673/1779650

Answer (score 0):

Não é preciso remover nada do código e manter a funcionalidade do clique no `body` para fechar o menu. Deixe seu código como está e adicione um `if` conforme abaixo.

Seu problema está em um `trigger` nesta parte do código que simula um click na página, fechando o menu:

```
// Carousel on Tabs of 'Unidades de Lazer'
tabCarousel = setInterval(function(){
   var active = tabNavItem.filter('.active'),
   next = active.next('li'),
   toClick = next.length ? next.find('a') : tabNavItem.eq(0).find('a');
   toClick.trigger('click');
}, 3500);
```

Adicione um `if` para verificar se o menu está aberto evitando que ele seja fechado sozinho:

```
// Carousel on Tabs of 'Unidades de Lazer'
tabCarousel = setInterval(function(){
   var active = tabNavItem.filter('.active'),
   next = active.next('li'),
   toClick = next.length ? next.find('a') : tabNavItem.eq(0).find('a');
   if($('.nav-toggler').hasClass('open')){ // este if
      toClick.trigger('click');
   }
}, 3500);
```